# Polarity of induced EMF in an LC oscillator

Tags: capacitance, electromagnetic-induction, oscillators, inductance

The image given belongs to my textbook (NCERT Grade 12, Chapter-7, Alternating Current, Pg No 255):
[image]
For your reference, this is the paragraph adjacent to the picture.
  [image]

I believe that the polarity of the induced EMF should be opposite to what is given.
Mathematically, the equation written using KVL seems correct with respect to Faraday's Law.
But when I think of it another way, the given EMF would only reinforce the increasing current in the circuit. Please help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*. . . . . the given EMF would only reinforce the increasing current in the circuit.*

In the title to the figure it says that "the current is increasing" and one must assume in the direction shown by the arrowhead adjacent to the current label $i$.

Lenz tells you that the inductor will produce an emf which oppose the increase in current.

I think that your confusion is due to you regarding the inductor as being like a resistor with current flowing from the terminal at the higher potential through the resistor to the terminal at a lower potential.
However consider what happens when a current is flowing out of the positive terminal of the battery and back into the negative terminal of the battery.
Inside the battery the current is flowing from the negative terminal to the positive terminal driven by an electrochemical reaction occurring within the battery.
So as the current is increasing within an inductor, the inductor sets up an emf to try and reduce the rate of increase of current, ie opposing the increasing current which flows from node $a$ to node $b$.